# Can I use Avenir Next (a font built-in to iOS) on an iOS app?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing

Avenir Next comes installed on every iPhone running iOS 9 and newer. Assuming my app only supports iOS 9 and up, is it permissible to style text with Avenir Next in my app?

The font isn’t embedded into the app itself— the app’s code bundle doesn’t contain the font file.

How has Apple licensed Avenir Next? Does their license permit them to allow apps on their phones to use the font? Furthermore, does Apple allow apps to use Avenir Next without a seperate license?

Answer (score 1):

*You* or your app are not using the font, your users are. And if they are in legal possession of an iPhone or iPad, they have a license that allows them to use all the fonts on the phone.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Can you provide a source?

Comment: Google for “Apple licenses”

Comment: https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/sla/

Comment: I went through the links there, but I didn't find anything specific on fonts/relevant to this question. Is there anything specific there that's relevant?